# Swift code for iOS won't sent out any HTTPS packet

Tags: swift, apache, https, jax-rs

IDE: Xcode 8.3.3
OS: Mac OS Sierra

We are currently making our app send POST HTTP request to our tomcat server, that running JAX-RS. Below is the code, for some reason, WireShark(A packet capture software) didn't capture any packet that send from iOS simulator. Can anybody find reason why?

```
// Method that send POST request
func completeRegisteration() {
    // Get session
    let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)

    // Prepare for registeration request
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://\(ServerInfo.serverIP):\(ServerInfo.port)/service/UserServices/RegisterUser")!)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "username=\(username)&emailAddress=\(emailAddress)&password=\(password)&phoneNumber=\(phoneNumber)&school=\(school)"
    urlRequest.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)

    // Generate task
    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {
        (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) -> Void in
        if(error != nil) {
            print(error.debugDescription)
        } else {
            print("Registeration Succeed!")
        }
    }

    // Start task
    task.resume()
}

// URLSessionDelegate Method, class already implemented URLSessionDelegate interface.
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
    completionHandler( URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.useCredential, URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try configuring your URLSession in this way

```
func completeRegisteration() {
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://\(ServerInfo.serverIP):\(ServerInfo.port)/service/UserServices/RegisterUser")!)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "username=\(username)&emailAddress=\(emailAddress)&password=\(password)&phoneNumber=\(phoneNumber)&school=\(school)"
    urlRequest.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(response)")
        }

        let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        print("responseString = \(responseString)")
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Umm, it says an SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made. Do you have any knowledge on how to establish SSL connection using Swift?

Comment: @YH.Liang  does your service accepts HTTPS call through port 443?

Comment: @Ning Right, the service accepts HTTPS call through port 8443. However, I realized that there are some problems happen on the server itself, and https set up should be fine.

Comment: @YH.Liang weird, try request though Post Man to debug your server. That's a powerful tool comes from Chrome.